# Adding a new attribute to super class of plotly Annotation object?

Tags: python, properties, attributes, plotly-dash, super

### Error message

After creating a super class that contains 1 additional attribute than the original `Annotation` class from Plotly, I am receiving error:

```
File "/home/name/git/snn/snncompare/src/snncompare/mwe0.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.edge = edge
  File "/home/name/anaconda/envs/snncompare/lib/python3.10/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py", line 4910, in __setattr__
    self._raise_on_invalid_property_error()(prop)
  File "/home/name/anaconda/envs/snncompare/lib/python3.10/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py", line 5070, in _ret
    raise _error_to_raise(
ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.layout.OtherAnnotation: 'edge'

Did you mean "name"?

    Valid properties:

...

Did you mean `name`?
```

### Attempt

In essence, I am not able to add a new attribute to the super attribute:

```py
from plotly.graph_objs.layout import Annotation

class OtherAnnotation(Annotation):
    def __init__(self, edge, *args, **kw):
        print(f'args={args}')
        print(f'kw={kw}')
        super(OtherAnnotation, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.edge = edge

def create_annotation_with_identifier():
    
    some_annotation= OtherAnnotation(
            edge="hello world", # ⭠ new parameter
            x=5,
            y=6,
            xref="x",
            yref="y",
            text="dict Text",
            align='center',
            showarrow=False,
            yanchor='bottom',
            textangle=90
    )
    print(some_annotation.edge)
```

### Question

Is it possible and advisable to create some sort of super/sub class that can function as the original `Annotation` object whilst carrying an extra property that is not in the `Annotation` object?

A work-around could be to create a new object named:

```py
class NewObject():
    def __init__(self, annotation:Annotation, extra_arg:str):
        self.annotation:Annotation=annotation
        self.extra_arg:str = extra_arg
```

However, I thought there may be a better way.